# Why I can't run/install g.rename.many?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, rename

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/g.rename.many.html "command not found".
I want to rename a huge amount of raster maps in GRASS as I need them to mask the region where I will run r.stats on a loop of another stack. Names of the two stack need to have a common string to make the loop run correctly. Pattern are absolutely similar now, but a very small difference make me need to rename them all:
raster to use as mask are: raster_species_1
whereas raster for which to run r.stats are: raster_species1
I have to change first stack, removing the "_" character, only solution seems, from my knowledge, using r.renmae.many, that I founded here https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/addons/g.rename.many.html
but my bash tells me "command not found".
Any help about r.rename.many? should I install it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The addon is called g.rename.many (r.rename.many does not exist...). You have to install it with `g.extension g.rename.many` or via the graphical user interface.

Comment: it does not work. Where can I find specific instructions? Or how can I do it trhought the graphical interface?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'svn' this is what it tells me

Comment: Please edit your questiion and add the full error message plus operating system information.